# Hold evaluation only once

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am looking for a way to define a pattern where the definition must not be completely evaluated right now.

Two complications: I cannot simply use `:=` instead of `=` (can I?) since some part in the argument *needs* to be evaluated. I was also not successfull with `Hold` (with using the extract-replace-trick to get my argument evaluted) since this `Hold` will survive forever - trouble is my pattern is also using another trick such that the expression containing `Hold` is actually not always returned (never when *I* write down my pattern explicitly, only when some other functions puts numbers in it), so my `ReleaseHold` does not find a Hold and disappears in effect.

I think something that Holds only once and does not put there the head `Hold`would save me. Otherwise, a `ReleaseHold` that does not disappear but puts a anti-Hold-head that stays there would also work, but not be as nice.

So here is my code, which is just trying to solve n equations for n parameters but the eqns containing numerical integrals:

```
Do[
    (*make an array eq[k] of patterns that do nothing 
      if they dont get specific numbers in a list ak_ and otherwise do NIntegrate *) 
 eq[k] [ak_?  (Function[list, And @@ NumericQ /@ list]) ] = 
  (
   ReplacePart[#1, #2 -> Extract[#1, #2]] & [
         (*NIntegrate needs to be Holded, but the Do-loop-k must be plugged in inside
           its argument, so extract it and put it back*)                            
    Hold[ NIntegrate[complicated functions for each k with appearance of ak[[k]]), {t, 0, l}, 
      MaxRecursion -> 50] ]
                                      ,  { 1, 1}    
     ]
   )
 , {k, n}] 

(*test*)
ReleaseHold[eq[3][{2,4,3,5,2}]] (*gives a number, great! (n=5 here) *)

eqns = Table[ReleaseHold[eq[i][ Table[a[j], {j, n}]]], {i, n}]  (*does not give an error since pattern is not evaluated, great!*)

vars = Table[{a[i],0},{i,n}]
FindRoot[eqns,vars]
         (*does not work since there is still 
          the Hold appearing now, ReleaseHold above was useless 
          since pattern was not evaluated and Hold not appearing*)
```

Comment: sorry for the messed up code tags, I don't see what is happening here... all after "Do" should be a code block

Comment: Perhaps try `Defer` and `Evaluate` instead of `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`.

Comment: does not seem to work... even the "gives-a-number-test line" is not evaluated to a number